# Eclipse Workspace Does Not Save (Vista)

Tags: windows, eclipse

I've recently upgraded to Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede), but I'm experiencing some intermittent issues with my workspace saving and loading on shutdown/startup.  The problems seems to be intermittent but occurs more frequently than not.  When I start Eclipse, the workspace does not load with the previously opened files and settings (no files are open and windows return to default locations).

I suspect that this may have something to do with UAC in Vista.  I am running Eclipse on Windows Vista Business 32-bit.

Any ideas?  At the minimum, it may be helpful to see if Eclipse is periodically saving the workspace, as it should - which files might I be looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be running into the virtualised folders issue.  UAC tries to silently stop apps from crashing but wont allow them to write to folders such as program files etc.  Try running eclipse as administrator and see if you get the same issue.  If so try moving your workspace folder into your user directory and see if that lets you get things done?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I do have the workspace located in my user directory, and I have tried running it as administrator, which does not seem to help.  Eclipse is also located in my user directory.

Comment: Running apps as Administrator should help, Ive had issues with a number of apps that attempt to write to their own or a non UserData directory and fail to write. If they aren't specifically coded to ask windows for privilege elevation when writing files I think they simply silently fail. (could be wrong, just seems that way)

Comment: If they aren't manifested, windows will virtualise the drives.  If they are, but aren't running as admin, they fail in spectacular fashion.  If running as admin isn't helping, there may be something else at play...

Comment: @Spence - I did a few more tests and it appears to be working now as administrator.  I found the files in .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench .  I really appreciate the help.